# Visual Studio Code - Integrated Terminal - Ctrl + Z

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code on Windows and using the integrated terminal with git-bash for Windows.

I just can't get the Ctrl+Z to work inside the integrated terminal, outside (external) it works just fine.
What can be wrong? How can I check why vscode is getting in the way with the Ctrl+Z shortcut?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do with ctrl+z?  There may be another way to accomplish it.

Comment: Ctrl + Z on git-bash should send the running command to the background in a stopped state. So I can resume it calling "fg", etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, there is no "undo" shortcut in terminal.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends `SIGSTOP` to whatever program is currently running, killing it without allowing it to clean up.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line) is a great post about <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in `bash`.

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) is the list of available shortcuts in VS Code, if you are interested.

Comment: Sending the SIGSTOP to it is actually what I want ;s

Answer (score 0):

Certain keymap extensions can do this in regular vscode. Try to uninstall them if this is in there, but terminals don't have an "Undo".

Comment: I kinda know about it but I still want the shortcut to go through the terminal window, because it's used to do another thing there. ;/

Thanks for the extensions tip, gonna try running it without extensions to see if anything changes.

Comment: disabling extensions didn't help at all ;/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.   Create your own keybinding in your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+z",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "kill -TSTP -1\u000D"
  },
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Use whatever options to that `kill` command you want.   `\u000D` is a return so it runs immediately.

`"text": "kill -CONT -1\u000D"` to resume the process.

Comment: well, it's a good try but you can't really sendSequences if the terminal is already running something ;/
what I am trying to achieve is the stop/resume of the running process, which should be possible running the Ctrl + Z -> fg 1, etc
dunno why vscode is getting in the way, running as an external terminal works just fine

PS: didn't know about the \u000D trick, that's really cool

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here for "undo" in the terminal, add the following to your keybindings.json (notice I'm using 'cmd' not 'ctrl'):

```
 { 
    "key": "cmd+z",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {"text":"\u001f"},
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Works on macOs Ventura 13.4.1